# How to play audio file from device storage?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

**Getting error**

The audio file is in my internal storage, it shows all the audio files in an listView, i want to play clicked audio file from the list but mediaPlayer.setDataResource() throws error:-

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Charso Bees (420) (DjPunjab.CoM): open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**Method for audio playing**

```
 private void playSong(File path, String fileName) {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + File.separator + fileName);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "playSong Exception--------", e);
    }
}
```

**onClick method**

```
 public void onItemClick(AudioClass audioClass) {

  File path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  playSong(path, audioClass.getTitle());
 }
```

Comment: This problem is resolved ,I was passing the wrong path for the audio file.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code as below and check runtime (Write External Storage) permission   before playing the file

```
 private void playSong(File fullFilePath) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
           Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fullFilePath);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context,uri )
            mediaPlayer.prepare()
            mediaPlayer.start()
         } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "playSong Exception--------", e);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pick the audio file from the storage

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOR_AUDIO_FILE);
            dialogAudio.dismiss();
```

in onActivityResult method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_FOR_AUDIO_FILE) {
    if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {

          Uri audioFileUri = data.getData();
    }
}
```

}

Play selected Audio

```
 try {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioFileUri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```